# How do I write to a CSV file with multiple commas?

Tags: java, csv

This is my code for the write file:

```
public void CreateCSV(PerfomanceBST[] temp) throws IOException {
    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("InstrumentationCSV.csv", "UTF-8")) {
        String out = "";
        String lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        for (PerfomanceBST each : temp) {
           out += each.MAX + "; " + each.MIN + "; " + each.getAverage() + "\r\n";
            //writer.write(out + "\r\n");
        }
        writer.print(out);
    }
}
```

it produces the 3 values into one column.

Comment: CSV, delimited by semicolons not commas? `;` is not the same as `,`

Comment: What are you hoping for, what happens, and why is that a problem?

Comment: I mean, there are dozens of different CSV formats. First you need to identify what format is expected by whatever tool will be reading it.

Answer (score -1):

Use below code, it will create Comma Separated CSV

```
public static void CreateCSV(){
        try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("/tmp/InstrumentationCSV.csv", "UTF-8")) {
            StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
            String lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator");
             for (PerfomanceBST each : temp) {
               out.append(each.MAX + ", " + each.MIN + ", " + each.getAverage() + "\r\n");
            }
            writer.print(out.toString());
        } catch (Exception e)  {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Why use a StringBuffer when you can use print directly?

Comment: No, it's more efficient to use `print` only: `writer.print(each.MAX); writer.print(", "); writer.print(each.MIN); ...`. It avoids unnecessary String objects and having the whole file data in memory.

Comment: Also, using `+` within `append` is poor style, because it creates a StringBuilder internally.

Comment: are you sure that every time using print (it will write into file) is more efficient. rather then printing every column value i can print at least one single row at a time

Comment: You can get rid of the lineSep business by using its `println`, too.